# firebase custom user signup

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm still a newbie in firebase so i might not have the right understanding of this excellent service.

I'm building a blogging mobile app in a client-server architecture in which most if not all the logic are done server-side. all the client does is request and display the result. the client-server communication will be in REST API. and post-processing data then will be pushed to firebase.
keep in mind that this is all still a work in progress and i still don't have an actual working setup yet.

my questions are:

1. is this possible?

2. is this good practice?

a 2nd architecture I'm thinking is to have the client talks with firebase directly and have the nodejs process any events coming from firebase.
same 2 questions as above
3. which is better?
mind you i'm also a newbie in nodejs and just start to learn nodejs for this purpose.

Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: See this blog post about common [application architectures with the Firebase Database](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/03/where-does-firebase-fit-in-your-app.html). Your second approach reads like pattern 2 in that post. But choosing the one that is best for your app is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.